# Are the extrema of a product of smooth positive functions the same as those of a sum of the same functions?

Tags: optimization

Given a couple of strictly positive functions, is optimizing the product of these functions equivalent to optimizing their sum? Any proof or counter example in the literature?

Comment: Note that if you want to optimize a product of two strictly positive functions, you can take a logarithm in order to obtain an expression that is a sum: $\mathrm{min}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]=\mathrm{min}[\ln f(x)+\ln g(x)]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Counterexample: take $f(x)=(x-1)^2+1$ and $g(x)=2x^2 + 1$. Then (calculated quickly using WolframAlpha):
$$\mathrm{min}[f(x)+g(x)]=\frac 1 3$$
$$\mathrm{min}[f(x)\cdot g(x)]\approx 0.273301$$

Comment: That was quick and straight to the point. Thanks Karlo.

Comment: I am wondering what condition must hold in order for those two to have the same extrema.

Comment: An example where your statement is satisfied: $f(x)=x^2 + 1,g(x)=(x-1)^2 + 1$, for which both the sum and the product are minimal for $x=\frac 1 2$.